# php accelerator review

Tags: php, caching, performance, accelerator

1) Can you recommend me a PHP accelerator for PHP V5.2.6?
2) Do you know about any recent test comparation/review of those modules(Alternative PHP Cache, eAccelerator, XCache, Zend Optimizer, Zend Platform, ionCube PHP Accelerator, Turck MMCache, Nusphere PhpExpress)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**APC**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) — standard choice, included in PECL, comes prepackaged in most Linux distros, to be bundled in by default in PHP6. As a bonus it can serve as [data cache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php) (something like local memcache).

eAccelerator was popular, for some time it was [the fastest](http://2bits.com/articles/benchmarking-drupal-with-php-op-code-caches-apc-eaccelerator-and-xcache-compared.html) bytecode cache. But the difference in speed is not enough to justify choosing it over APC.

Turck MMcache — dead. eAccelerator was forked from it.

ionCube — dead.

Answer (score 5):

[APC](http://www.php.net/apc) is pretty much the standard choice. It's scheduled to be included in PHP 6 core. Unlike most of the other candidates, it's stable and it's free.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a comparison of three of them, APC, Zend and XCache:

http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2007/12/23/php-accelerators-apc-vs-zend-vs-xcache-with-zend-framework/

Answer (score 1):

APC is easy to install, works out of the box and can be used as both an opcode cache and a data cache. Easy choice, in my opinion.